# Sign string in pkcs7 standard with openssl and usb token

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, pkcs#11, pkcs#7

I looking for way to sign string with pkcs7. Certificate is on usb token. I think should be option to use pkcs11 API from openssl and provide lib (drivers) to token reader. But after two days searches i'm in enter point.

Maybe someone did something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`PKCS#7` signing is out of scope of `PKCS#11` standard.

It is possible to code the `PKCS#7` signing by sequence of calls to `PKCS#11` library for hash an sign.

Some vendors have build-in `extensions` to support `PKCS#7` signing trough supplied `PKCS#11` library.

All of token vendors that I have been worked with, have their own `extensions` inside of `PKCS#11` library to support feature you are talking about.

Please refer to documentation of your USB token manufacturer.